# Can I disable a specific annoying advertisement?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, advertising

I don't mind advertising in general on [S[OFU]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354), but I don't like a specific one. Is it possible to ask that you don't see a specific advertisement again, without doing some [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) magic?

**Background:** The one I don't like is the "Case of the Mondays?".

Comment: "I believe you'd get your ass kicked saying something like that, man." http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lV7DzFP6FUY

Comment: I bet I'd really get my ass kicked if I said what I thought about the ad.

Comment: @Jeff no-one seems to like that ad - maybe you could just .. put it out of its misery..

Comment: It can't be *that* bad. Can it?

Comment: How come this question got a sudden burst of activity? Was there a dulicate asked or something?

Comment: A dupe indeed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46057/ads-on-stack-overflow-closed

Comment: And another one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46627/case-of-the-mondays-ad-closed

Comment: CASE OF EQUALS THE MONDAYS?

Comment: Make it stop.  If this were IRL you'd "get your ass kicked" forthwith!

Comment: I don't get it.  It's an ad.  Can't you just ignore it?

Comment: And I thought it was just me, but got my question duped to this one ... now I see it's not just me ... I really hate ads but I understand that they want to make money ... but please could you exercise some final veto over the ad design? I guess we all got spoiled by Apple who makes sure that their users only get the best and the most beautiful stuff but still ...

Comment: And now a bounty??? How's that going to help?

Comment: @George: I followed your advice. I'm bashing my head against the wall.

Comment: ad blockers to the rescue!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Case of the Mondays* is [gone for good](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84514/is-the-case-of-the-mondays-ad-gone-for-good), with the switch from [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers) to Careers 2.0.

Answer (score 31):

We are looking into whether this is possible--it depends mostly on AdZerk, our ad-serving provider. I think it's actually a good idea to put close boxes on ads which muffle a given ad (or a given advertiser?) for a particular user. If you don't like the ad or advertiser, there's no sense in showing it to you. And we could use the data we get back from this to identify ads that are inappropriate for our audience or unusually offensive, or to show you ads that you care more about.

Answer (score 28):

## GET RID OF THE ADVERTISEMENT!!!

I hate it.

**Solutions:**

- Send massive amounts of spam to Stack Overflow until they get rid of it (anyone want to make a spambot?)
- Yell until your coworkers come to see what you are yelling at and then tell *them* to send massive amounts of spam to Stack Overflow
- Bang your head against the wall until the doctor comes to examine your head. Then tell *him* to... oh you get the idea.

Comment: Uh, you seem to be getting *overly* upset about an image on the internet.  What's the big deal?  We see annoying adverts on the telly, hear them on the radio, etc. and we manage to ignore those.

Comment: @Andy: Ya but this is **more** than annoying - it's downright evil.

Answer (score 13):

You can't do this with Adblock Plus if you normally have it turned on for every site, but add an exception for stackoverflow. There's no way to add an exception to an exception.

Here is a greasemonkey script; unfortunately, the ad still flashes on screen for a second :(

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Remove case-of-the-mondays
// @namespace      http://example.com/
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/
// ==/UserScript==

var crap = document.evaluate(
  "//img[@src='http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/case-of-the-mondays-careers.png']",
  document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null
);

for (var i=0;i<crap.snapshotLength;i++) {
   var img = crap.snapshotItem(i);
   img.parentNode.removeChild(img);
}
```

Seriously, does anyone **like** that ad? Can we just kill it please?

Comment: or you could just not whitelist the SO ads...

Answer (score 12):

Ask your friendly ad blocker to block that particular ad alone. From what I can see, each ad image has a different name, allowing you to block only that.

Comment: I guess an "ad blocker" falls under the same category as "grease monkey magic".

Comment: Well, the monkey is hidden behind the blocker, so your hands won't be greasy :P

Answer (score 8):

Here's a Stylish "script". Like the Greasemonkey scripts, but without the delay.

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

img[src*=case-of-the-mondays-careers]
{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: How would you include this script on each SO page?

Comment: It's now possible to avoid the delay in a userscript with most userscript engines, using `@run-at document-start`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another GM script, this one uses JQuery to take the offending image out. Not that there's anything wrong with the other one, I just like tweaking these things.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           so-office-space-hater
// @namespace      so
// @description    Exclude Office Space ad from SO
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
(function(){
  unsafeWindow.jQuery('img[src$="ads/case-of-the-mondays-careers.png"]').remove();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one has said this. You can use [AdBlock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/). Whitelist the site to allow ads. Right click the offending image and select block image (it should be last item in menu). A dialog pops up and you can select custom which will block only that specific image instead the the entire site or range.

Comment: That's what [alex](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-i-disable-a-specific-annoying-ad/36081#36081) meant with "Ask your friendly ad blocker to block that particular ad alone."

Comment: oops. well, i'm surpise no one said to use adblock to get rid of it. although i did see one say you cant :|. which i have done many times. It isnt hard to find either.

Comment: I don't see the Block Image option in the context menu. If I "disable ad-block on this page", all I get in the context menu is "Re-enable ad-block on this page". If instead I don't disable ad-block, but add an exception for "ads.stackoverflow.com", none of the ad images have "block image" in their context menus. Un-whitelisted images like the logo do though.

Comment: your right. regex on whitelist doesnt work so it appears its impossible :(. I deserve a -1