# Ads that contains erotic images

Tags: discussion, advertising, etiquette

Hi,

recently when I use stack overflow I started to see the "Show us yours" ad, a women with very short skirt siting with a laptop in a sexy way.

What a distraction, when I try to answer or read a question this ad takes attention in a way (negatively) that affects my answer or understanding the question.

And I'm sure many will feel the same thing with sexy images that are put in front of them while answering or reading a question and answers.

Does anyone feel or think the same?

And wouldn't it be better to filter ads that contains some erotic parts since it is a site about programming?

**UPDATE:**

After seeing your comments I would like to say something about it.

First I never agree to use skin for marketing and selling products and I consider it not professional humiliating and as @devinb said "condescending" and should not be supported in any way.

Most of you considered this ad as a way to make enough attention to click on it just as a normal tactic and it doesn't have provocative scene in it. Well if this was the case why didn't they put a man instead, why wouldn't you do that!? Because they want to stimulate men's desire on women skin to click on it. And you have to know provocative varies from person to other depending on his personality and the culture. In addition, provocative doesn't mean that it will turn on your sexual desire.

**It doesn't distract!**

well let's see, when you click at the ad and go to their page you will see they only put the upper half of the image and they put some white shadow at bottom of it. The creators of this ad edited it for their own website, it is ok in other sites but not ok on their own site. Why?

Is it provocative? Is it distraction? Is it erotic?

Some would say yes, or no, or maybe I'm wrong I don't know!

But is it acceptable to use skin or sexual scene as a marketing tactic? No said Jeff Atwood in his article "How Not to Advertise on the Internet ".

And hence, I don't think any reasonable person would classify it as an acceptable method since it is the first step towards idiocracy.

Comment: Try going to a Microsoft MVP site looking for some help with coding and see an ad for this Evony game stretch down the right margin. The model is wearing flesh colored lingerie laying out on a silk sheet (IIRC). Now, *that* is distracting.

Comment: you've also likely wasted a fair amount on time writing/monitoring/responding to this question on Meta when you could have installed an ad blocker...

Comment: I got distracted, trying to figure out what "Kron" might mean.

Comment: @dboarman: Now, them Evony ads *are* distracting.

Comment: @davidsleeps: I don't want to use ad block because I do click at these ads and I see them useful.
for the rest you have to know you are not alone in the world some regions have their own restricts, what you see it normal other regions see it different.I have seen people close a website (in browser) for less. to you it is ok but the place where I live (for now depending on the contract) it is not. they will keep refreshing the browser till other ad comes out. considering other regions to me is important too.

Comment: So, everything should be changed because *some* feel offended, or even feel *aroused*, by a scene that in many other parts of the word *is* just life as we know it? Not my idea of a world where people take into consideration how others feel. Shouldn't such consideration be based on compromises, not on dictatorship?

Comment: @Arjan The purpose of meta is for people to raise any issues they have with the site. His question/opinion are perfectly valid and do not need to be abused. You can disagree with him, but there's no need to imply that he's trying to attack your way of life.

Comment: @devinb: Thank you for clearing out the point I wanted to say, I just surprised when I saw the down-votes on this question like it is attacking some one, while it is a normal question not attended to insult any one.

Comment: @Kronass On Meta, people downvote when they disagree as well. So, the downvotes are (in this case) simply saying that other people do not consider that particular ad as problematic.

Comment: @Juanma: or rather the other way around: he gets *too easily* aroused by women.

Comment: @devin & Kronass: I was just responding to "considering other regions to me is important too". I was not trying to be impolite or anything like that (and I don't feel threatened at all).

Comment: I like sexy photos. Nothing against them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> wouldn't be better to filter ads that
>   contains some erotic parts since it is
>   a site about programming?

I would agree.  Unfortunately, the entire point of ads is to distract you.  Ads that are better at distracting are worth more money.

Consider installing an ad-blocker or GreaseMonkey script to remove the adverts that are overly distracting.

Comment: yes ads do some distraction but  not in a way that will effect on your work, specially the erotic ones makes more problems then solution

Comment: All adds affect you, otherwise nobody would pay for them

Comment: This is the part that I'm talking about it, ad that will effect at your work in a bad way. consider this, you are facing a bug and you are trying to fix it and while visiting a support site to help you in it you see a women with bikini good ad and all now back to your problem, are you now focused and in mentality that allows you to keep productive like 30 minutes ago or just decreased in a way that disturbs on your productivity, that support site instead of making you more productive did the reverse thing, some times the ad will causes more loses to the site the profits in none-tangible way.

Comment: @Kronass, if an *advert* affects you enough to put you off your work then you need to get out more.

Answer (score 15):

I checked I do not find this ad provocative, and I don't think any reasonable person would classify it as *erotic*.

Comment: Yes this was the images, but my question was more general then this image. to many people I know this image is a distracting I wouldn't prefer them to see it when they start a real work.

Comment: Hmm... I can't see the image because I have *ads.stackoverflow.com* resolving *localhost* in my hosts file (sorry Jeff, sometimes they slow the site down a bit too much and I ignore ads anyway).  @Kronass: I think Stack Overflow is more of a distraction from work than adverts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Andy E's head: I Agree :)

Comment: @Jeff, Considering your blog post about evony, I think he has a reasonable point. This ad is very clearly using sex as a tool to get attention which, while being a completely normal advertising tactic, is one which you very specifically claimed to not approve of. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/how-not-to-advertise-on-the-internet.html

Comment: I do, but I liiiiiike it!

Comment: All I see is a lady, with a laptop, in a skirt. Maybe it's because I work in an office that has ladies who have laptops and occasionally wear skirts, but I just can't see that as being erotic or provocative, and especially not in the degree like discussed in the blog.

Comment: @ccomet, The question is which part of the ad is designed to inform you about the product, and which part is designed to catch your eye. This ad is using a woman's legs to attract your eye (which has nothing to do with the product) and then is trying to get you to click. I don't find the ad or the practice objectionable in ANY way, but to claim that the ad just *happens* to have a woman in it, is naive or condescending.

Comment: @devinb I didn't say, nor did I mean to imply, the ad "just happens to have a woman in it". I said that I don't find that particular image provocative or erotic. To me, maybe not to you, but that image is no more "provocative" or "erotic" than the ad [discussed in this old post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13165/), which also uses a female figure to attract your eye.

Comment: I don't understand how somebody could find this distracting. Most people see more bare skin on billboards outside their window. Not to talk about a lot of ads on mainstream web sites.

Comment: @questions speaking of which, your gravatar is SUCH a tease.

Comment: @Jeff that's just the beginning. How about some more of them hairy legs! I think I'll make some new pictures later.

Comment: I made an update..

Comment: @@wood: You don't consider "Show Us Yours" a double entendre?

Comment: FWIW, I don't consider this ad appropriate for a professional site. It's not just that the image is PG rather than G, but the tag line "show us yours" seems a bit too much.

Comment: Image is broken.

Comment: @andrew does it really matter? the OP description of "a women with very short skirt siting with a laptop in a sexy way." should suffice. It was a sideways shot with only the laptop and legs visible.

Answer (score 4):

The answers to this question should be able to help you out..."[Can I disable a specific annoying ad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-i-disable-a-specific-annoying-ad)"

Answer (score 4):

Is *that* an **erotic image**?

Sorry pal, but I don't see the resemblance with the [Ebony ads](http://www.lazygamer.co.za/general-news/a-history-of-evony-ads-the-insanity-continues).

Really, it's suggestive, but nothing more. It's just a patch of photoshoped plain skin.

Personally, I find [lady bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-advertisement-gallery/40607#40607) and [mammoths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34181/stack-overflow-advertisement-gallery/40827#40827) attractive, but I don't rally against those ads.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that the ads are erotic, unethical or NTSFW, but using breasts to shift source control software does annoy me somewhat.

And the guy on the bottom right isn't looking at his notes...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is obviously intentionally provocative.

I've resisted adblockers up to this point, but since Jeff made the point that this kind of ad will be allowed, then I will start using them now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this ad in a while, and haven't seen any sexist ads lately on Stack Exchange. Like the [Mondays ad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-i-disable-a-specific-annoying-ad) I guess it's not so much [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) but [status-bydefault](/questions/tagged/status-bydefault).

Answer (score -5):

> do any one feel or think the same thing

Nope.  By the way, your description sounds like you're in love with her. Uh, pal, she's not yours, you have to learn to live with it ;-(

IMHO beautiful girls with laptops are hot!  Please, don't remove any.

Comment: yes of-course when you own a company and you have bunch of geeks who your work depends on them, let me see how they will do the work with a sexy secretary with a laptop in the same room

Comment: @Kro: Easy, "If we don't meet our deadline, *she* gets fired!"

Comment: seen this, heard that, she never got fired.