# Rude user refusing to take advice

Tags: discussion, behavior, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I report a specific bad user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66444/how-can-i-report-a-specific-bad-user)

A few minutes ago there was a comment in the flagged queue from a user saying that he was offended because the OP uses a religious *meme* in his username. The comment was quickly deleted.

I was intrigued by that kind of intolerance and browsed the user's comments history, finding a lot of aggressive behavior. Also, when other user reminded him the "Be nice" motto, he answered along the lines of *Don't tell me how to answer, mind your own business* (the text is not exact, just to preserve identities).

So, we have a bully, and he has been warned to no avail. What's next?

Comment: Do you mean [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/569730/restrisiko?tab=activity) commented to [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/674029/jesus-is-lord?tab=stats)'s [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797514/python-plone-passing-data) like [this](http://i.imgur.com/ywAVF.png)?

Comment: I take more offence at that user name, than at the comment that discusses that name. And the user name being the first "to post" an implicit comment, I'd say: please ban that user name.

Comment: Damn! YOU blew up my undercover operation

Comment: @Arjan Feel free to be offended. I'm not talking about that specific comment.

Comment: Luckily, I'm not easily offended. :-) That specific example makes me wonder though: *who* deleted the comment and why was that user name not taken care of too then.

Comment: @Arjan Usernames don't come with a grey flag attached. Yet.

Comment: @Arjan: Why would that username have to be "taken care of"? I couldn't put it better than one of the comments found behind one of YOU's links: *It's just as offensive as saying "Red is Blue"*. It might be offensive if it would say "A is B" where "B" is something bad, but in this case B isn't even something bad... How can that ever be offensive?

Comment: @fretje, because it works as a red flag on some. There's no need for such user name, or any religious or political user name on most of the SE sites. (In this context, B implies "best" or "truth" or whatever, while others think another another A is that, or none A at all. Love riddles!)

Comment: @Popular Thanks. Used the wrong search keywords.

Comment: @Arjan Citing you :D http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51736/ads-that-contains-erotic-images  _So, everything should be changed because some  feel offended, or even feel aroused, by a scene that in many other parts of the word is just life as we know it? Not my idea of a world where people take into consideration how others feel. Shouldn't such consideration be based on compromises, not on dictatorship?_

Comment: "Jesus is Borg" would be offensive. But that user name? Live and let live.

Comment: Good find, @wether ;-) Still, I don't really think it's the same, except for *"a world where people take into consideration how others feel"*. To me, that user name does not take that into account. The ads serve a purpose for these sites, the user name does not.

Comment: Ah, @MPelletier, if *that* would be offensive, then why is the other not? I really think saying "A is B" implies "So, *your* C is not B".

Comment: @Arjan: I have to agree with Wether here... I don't think that a username should be changed because it can work as a red flag on some... In that regard, we better don't let the user change their username at all, and let them all be "user1234567", and even then I think someone will be offended.

Comment: @Arjan I thought in that case "A is B" would translate to "*your* A is not C". But in reality, if the user's name is "I eat pancakes", I don't limit my interpretation of the person behind the name to someone who eats pancakes, I assume there's some other thing they eat and do. TL;DR: what's in a name? not much

Comment: On my way to work today I passed cars with bumper stickers and even vanity plates that expressed religious views. I also had to drive by houses of worship. And now this. It's been a tough day, but I think I can make it if I can manage to grow up and act like an adult.

Comment: @Arjan - you might find this blog post interesting: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/25/maybe-there-s-something-wrong-with-the-universe-but-probably-not.aspx If you don't care about compilers (but you probably do) you can stop after the 4th paragraph.

Comment: So, if I would change my user name to "A is dead" (a fact in every religion, I suppose) then that would be fine? (Sorry for focussing on that very example comment; but meanwhile we know the main issue is handled in the duplicate anyhow?)

Comment: @tvanfosson, :-) But I don't (yet) think I'm in the ladies room. (Or, more precisely, as I'm actually kind of defending the one who first commented on that user name: I don't think the first commenter is in the wrong room either.)

Comment: @Arjan: I guess that would be debatable. My only point was "Let it go. Move along." That's what I do. See @status-declined's awesome comment.

Comment: @Arjan - at some point you have to distinguish between *disagreement* and *offense*.  Not everything you disagree with is offensive.  I think you also need to distinguish between something that offends *you* and something that is offensive *in and of itself*.  The latter is more of a community than a personal standard and what should be applied in this context.

Comment: Agreed, @MPelletier, that is what I do too. But here the comment of someone who criticized the name was flagged and deleted. (While at the same time that same user helpfully answered the question, and even improved it a bit. It could even have been a self-deletion, of course.)

Comment: @Arjan et al: I understand the new topic is motivational, but please keep in mind it is not the issue in this question (perhaps someone interested could post a "What to do with offensive usernames?" one). I just mentioned the username issue to introduce the fact that I went ahead to read the user's comment history. I think this question is a dupe, and should be closed. Please help with that.

Comment: The user is a bit abrasive, but he mostly has a point. Not sure what should be done here... Flagging is definitely the right thing to do,  the mods can keep track of repeat offenders, and will eventually give a warning shot. Re the user name, I think it's really lame to show off your faith in such an obnoxious way on a programming site. But it's probably nothing to get too excited about, as @status-declined so nicely puts it.

Comment: @Pekka's I think the _"Be nice"_ guideline is the better and most importatnt in the site. Much more important than "_keep within the scope_", as the later is easily enforced, while the first guarantees continual self-destructive flame wars if avoided.

Comment: @Wether: motivational, you say? It's a powder keg! Of joy! Nevertheless, sorry.

Comment: I simply *cannot* wrap my mind around what could possibly be offensive about that user name. Offensive doesn't mean "I disagree with their conclusions/beliefs".

Answer (score 10):

Flag the rude behavior for moderator attention and one of us will look into it.

Comment: If we fire back with a snide/sarcastic comment such as *"May you always exhibit the level of professionalism seen here today"* or *"I can only imagine how fun you must be to work with on a daily basis"*, will moderators be more dismissive towards our rude/offensive flags directed at the same user?

Comment: @crush We don't actually see who cast comment flags, so no.  Your comment will probably just be deleted too.