# Does the adding of moderator-only tags show up in a user's activity?

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, moderator-tags

Jeff Atwood recently added the moderator-only tag "status-declined" to [Can I disable a specific annoying ad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-i-disable-a-specific-annoying-ad).

I tried looking at his recent activity page, to see if his declining was done soon after he gave an answer or comment to a related question. But even though his action was apparently recent enough to appear in his activity page, it wasn't there. His oldest activity is currently December 4, and he added the tag on approximately December 8.

Is this because "status-declined" is a moderator-only tag?

Comment: [This revision](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/68216/revisions) shows up in his activity tab (that's how I found it). There is some grouping that goes on in that area (exact algorithm unknown), so the edit and answer could be grouped together possibly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, will be fixed in the next deploy

Comment: Have you tried looking at Jeff's activity tab?

Comment: yerp ... if you edited tags on 2 questions in a row using the 10k edit tag thingy, 1 of the revs would be missing

Comment: Ooh, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52967/same-summary-revisions-should-not-be-merged-in-the-activity-tab-of-a-users-profi) is finally getting fixed? Nice.