# Is the "Case of the Mondays?" ad gone for good?

Tags: discussion, advertising

With the switch from Careers to Careers 2.0, is the "Case of the Mondays?" ad gone for good?

Comment: Awww, does someone have a case of the Mondays?

Comment: @Farseeker ... more like "somebody has the case of the case of the Mondays" :)

Comment: Teacher .. Teacher ... **YOU FORGOT TO GIVE US HOMEWORK!!**

Answer (score 8):

Gosh, I'm glad you mentioned this, because that reminds me! I was thinking we should bring this ad back.. for old times' sake..

I'll get that implemented now!

Comment: Yessssssss!!!!!

Comment: So the status for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-i-disable-a-specific-annoying-ad/84575 is `status-back-by-popular-demand`?

Comment: @Andrew - @Popular Demand had nothing to do with it.

Comment: "**it is not welcome in our community** -- This answer contains content that a reasonable person would consider offensive, abusive, or hate speech." My trigger finger is itching...