# Choose to not show specific advertisements

Tags: feature-request, advertising

I spend a fair amount of time at work on SO, whether it's trying to find questions I can answer, asking my own, or searching for other topics that can help me.

I have a concern with the advertisements for careers.stackoverflow being on my webpage constantly. Because people walk by my desk and I don't want them to think I'm on a job search site. No one's said anything about it and it doesn't make me use the site less, I'd just would prefer it to not show, lest co-workers start getting suspicious.

[image: Careers 2.0 ad]

I have no problem with advertising; obviously it makes SO money. So I don't want to use an adblocker. I know this is similar to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-i-disable-a-specific-annoying-ad) but the difference here is that the careers ad is an internal ad and not one that is being paid for by an outside source.

Can a feature be added to disable specific internal ads or generally reduce internal ads in place of more outside ads?

***Edit***
And then I realized I have no idea of the business practices of the SE network and whether or not there is money changing hands between sites, but I'll assume the simple case that
they are all the same

Comment: If you are afraid of the negative reactions of your boss/coworkers, you *should* use Careers. Better now than later.

Comment: Actually, the "Case of the Mondays" ad was for Careers 1.0, if I'm not mistaken. It's still a different ad though.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer well played. but I'm not really a programmer by trade, just do it for this company. so I don't think I'd be very qualified for jobs on careers.so

Comment: @Grace Note  Also I'm not complaining about it being annoying in the sense of the wording (or should I say copy) of the ad.

Comment: I'm aware of why you want the ad hidden (don't want the boss to see it), and I'm not saying it's a duplicate. Just pointing out that it's not actually a difference of internal ad versus outside source ad - they're both internal.

Comment: I don't want it hidden per se, I'd be ok with it being replaced by another ad.