# Avoid ads for products I already own

Tags: feature-request, advertising

I find that some well known companies in Java world (Jetbrains, Zeroturnaround) advertise quite a lot on SO. I already have their products (both of them actually), so this advertisement is a waste for me and them too. Would be nice if I could disable the ads from specific companies. I don't want to downvote the ad, because it feels as if I didn't like the product, which is not the case (quite the opposite actually).

Comment: Too much work for way too little gain... just ignore them same way you ignore them all around the internet. Or reload.

Comment: How is the system supposed to  know which products you already have?

Comment: Highly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97917/choose-to-not-show-specific-advertisements

Comment: @Jan I assume OP here means button like "ignore future ads about this product".

Comment: @JanDvorak I am not proposing that system should know automatically, just being able to told the system would be enough

Comment: why the downvotes? If you don't like the suggestion it doesn't mean that question itself is unclear or not showing research effort.

Comment: You propose a feature request.  People vote on that request.  Upvotes are people saying "I think that's a good and useful idea, and support it." Downvotes mean "I hate puppies, laughter, and OP.  I want death and hatred to reign.  Therefore, I am going to take away your fake imaginary internet points."  Isn't it obvious?  Why would you even have to wonder about the downvotes?  Are you being obtuse on purpose?

Comment: @Won't well, the popup for downvote says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" , if somebody thinks that's the case, I would like to understand why, that doesn't seem to be obtuse to me

Comment: Now you're being obtuse.  People downvote to show disagreement.  Ask a FR to change the text if you can't see beyond it.

Comment: OK, you made me to read help about meta and it actually says that voting on feature-request questions can be used to vote about usefulness of the feature itself. Didn't know that, sorry

Comment: People still see ads?  Seriously?

Comment: I use uBlock normally, however on some sites it seems fair to me not to block the ads, SO being the case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The downvote module that appears when you hover over an ad can act as a solution to your problem: [image: downvote-meh-20150219]

For your situation I'd say 'Other' applies.

While I acknowledge that this does not disable *all* ads for a particular advertiser or product, it allows you to control which ads you see. I think blocking all ads from Advertiser X is not the best solution. Consider the possibility that an advertiser like ZT or JetBrains, whose current products you already use, releases an update or a new product and chooses to promote it by advertising on SO. You may benefit from still seeing ZT or JetBrains ads.

Alllllll that said: we hear you. As stated above, I think the downvote module should work for your use-case. Let me know if you have any additional feedback, though.

---

As a reminder, relevant blog about the voting module [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/11/get-rid-of-ads-you-dont-like-and-encourage-ads-you-do-like/).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know there is menu under down-thumb button, I didn't try to press it, bc I though it would mean I don't like the add. I think this is a good solution

Comment: @saberduck While writing my answer that exact possibility occurred to me. I wonder how many other people don't downvote something they simply want to hide out of concern for negatively affecting the ad.

Comment: maybe adding ellipsis (…) symbol when cursor hovers over the button to provide suggestion that action is not immediate

Comment: Hmm... that may work.

Comment: Can we just add "I already have/use this?" to that? Seems a meaningful enough use case.