# Will the incoming Affiliate Ads be held to an accessibility standard?

Tags: discussion, advertising, accessibility

The Web_Content_Accessibility_Guidelines ([WCAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Content_Accessibility_Guidelines)) provide a set of success criteria to help devs ensure our content is accessible to folks with disabilities. Will the [Affiliate Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306737/affiliate-ads-are-coming-to-the-network) be subject to these or similar criteria?

Comment: I've just pinged the folks on the ads team so they know to come chime in when they get a moment, hang tight :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for this question. I’m the lead on this project and can assure you that we will absolutely take all criteria set by the WCAG in mind as we roll out Amazon affiliate ads on the handful of sites we've identified. Our policy has always been to provide relevant advertising in a minimally obtrusive way, and the affiliate ads are no exception. We actively work to prevent ads from harming or impeding our users' ability to navigate our sites.

These ads will not be animated or contain any flash which includes the carousel style ads you might have seen other sites run. Like all other ads we currently run on sites that accept advertising, the ads will be static images and will be clearly delineated from content.

And of course, once affiliate ads are rolled out, we will continue to monitor Meta discussions, and any issues regarding accessibility will be addressed immediately.

Comment: "ads will not be animated or contain any flash..." [Is that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329547/ads-on-se-sites-are-excessively-animated-irrelevant-dubious-and-resource-inten) still [true](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/were-testing-advertisements-on-the-workplace)? If not, could you please update this answer to the real answer to the question?

Comment: @WBT The ads that this answer is referring to have not been run in over a year . Note that during their time, no animated ads were shown as they were not a part of that campaign. To address your concern (and as I've stated in the links you shared) we are planning on continuing to show selected/curated animated ads during the ads experiment for the SE network.

Comment: @JuanM, "Our policy has always been to provide relevant advertising in a minimally obtrusive way.... We actively work to prevent ads from harming or impeding our users' ability to navigate our sites." This part is not specific to the affiliate ads. Has this policy changed?