# Report crypto mining phishing site of Stack Overflow and NSFW ads

Tags: discussion

After browsing Google Search looking for a specific answer, I ran into a phishing website or similar (first page in Google search). It looks exactly the same as the legitimate Stack Overflow site. The site also displays [not safe for work](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NSFW#Adjective) (NSFW) ads (which was really a weird thing to find on a Stack Exchange site).

URL
`https://bfhj.cryptoo.live/questions/33074940/angular-filter-hangs-on-large-data`

Screen (NSFW!!): `https://i.imgur.com/N8AOaTs.jpg`

I could also open the site using the Tor browser, so it is not just malware on my end, I think.

Comment: Actually.... Stack Exchange also started to [display dubious ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329547/ads-on-se-sites-are-excessively-animated-irrelevant-dubious-and-resource-inten). Not on Stack Overflow so far, but after the "test" will be over I'm 100% sure those ads will reach SO as well. They claim they remove bad ads after they are reported, but they can't promise new bad ads won't show again.

Comment: In this case though, its a fake/scraper. At least untul something like that turns up on SE, can we please keep the conspiracy theories to a minimum?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek sure, never claimed that site belongs to SE in any way, just stated a fact they served bad ads, as it's relevant here. (In response to "really weird thing to find on a stack site")

Comment: Uhm, having looked at the link, hopefully nothing ever that bad.